# Get number of weeks in Spotfire

Tags: spotfire

I am new to Spotfire and am having trouble extracting the number of weeks from a date range and passing it to an expression.

When I manually enter the # of weeks and pass it to this expression for a calculated column it works fine when the date filter is set to the same # of weeks.

```
case when [dw] in ('Monday', 'Thursday', 'Friday') then ([usage] / (${Weeks} * 3 * 540))
when [dw] in ('Tuesday', 'Wednesday') then ([usage] / (${Weeks} * 2 * 510))
else 0
end
```

However, when I try and automate it by using a property control with the expression;
    uniqueCount(week([date]))
or create a calculated column and pass the value anywhere it doesn't work.

I know the "week(column)" returns the week in numbers 1 - 54 so you should be able to get the total # of weeks in a range. I just don't see a way to do it, so any help is welcome.

My date data looks like this;

Location  useDate
     1  2016-07-11 00:00:00.000
     1  2016-07-12 00:00:00.000
     1  2016-07-13 00:00:00.000
     1  2016-07-14 00:00:00.000
     1  2016-07-15 00:00:00.000
     1  2016-07-18 00:00:00.000
     1  2016-07-19 00:00:00.000
     1  2016-07-20 00:00:00.000
     1  2016-07-21 00:00:00.000
     1  2016-07-22 00:00:00.000
     1  2016-07-25 00:00:00.000
     1  2016-07-27 00:00:00.000
     1  2016-07-28 00:00:00.000
     1  2016-07-29 00:00:00.000
     2  2016-07-12 00:00:00.000
     2  2016-07-13 00:00:00.000
     2  2016-07-14 00:00:00.000
     2  2016-07-15 00:00:00.000
     2  2016-07-20 00:00:00.000
     2  2016-07-21 00:00:00.000
     2  2016-07-22 00:00:00.000
     2  2016-07-25 00:00:00.000
     2  2016-07-26 00:00:00.000
     2  2016-07-27 00:00:00.000
     2  2016-07-28 00:00:00.000
     2  2016-07-29 00:00:00.000
     3  2016-07-19 00:00:00.000
     3  2016-07-20 00:00:00.000
     4  2016-07-19 00:00:00.000
     4  2016-07-20 00:00:00.000

Chris

Comment: what are you going to do with the # of weeks you get? Filter data... display it in the text area... etc?

Comment: I don't know how your data looks like, as you haven't provided any. But can't you Insert > Calculated Column: `DateDiff('wk', [startColumn], [endColumn])` ?

Comment: Maybe I am going about this wrong but I am trying to get the number of weeks in a date range provided by the filter in the text area. then use that # to calculate several percentages. I am not sure how to reference the date filter in Spotfire. the DateDiff may work if I can get input from the filter. I will try and post some data.

Comment: This is doable if you are ok filtering the data with a property control instead of the default filter. Is this ok?

Comment: Anything to allow this to work I am up for. how do I need to configure the property control?